# eventClick delete function works only for 2nd click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function that, upon click will delete a scheduled event but it only works when clicked the second time. The first time I click it asks me "Do you really want to delete this?" so the prompt works, but the actual delete only happens if I go through this a second time.

```
eventClick: function(event) {
    var decision = confirm("Do you really want to delete this?");
    if (decision==true) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "delete_events.php",
            data: '&id=' + event.id,
            type: "POST",  
        });
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id);
    } else {
    }
},
```

Here's the delete_events.php:

```
<?php
   $id = $_POST['id'];
    //connection to the database
    $sql = "DELETE from evenement WHERE id=".$id;
    $q = $bdd->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute();
?>
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Add console.log(event.id) in your if (decision==true) and see it logs with the correct id on the first click.

Comment: Also try url: "delete_events.php?id=" + event.id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that after adding an event, the calendar did not re-fetch (refresh) events and probably not the ID properly. I solved my problem by doing

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

upon adding an event, and the delete now works with the first click.

Thanks